# Returning values from a OpenGL ES 2.0 shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to get any values out of a OpenGL ES 2.0 shader? I'd like to use the gpu to do some processing (not 3D). The only thing I could think of is to render to the canvas and then to use readPixels to get the colors (preferably in a large 2d array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's called GPGPU. The only way is to draw to a framebuffer or a texture, [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial.html) is a tutorial that explains it, just stick to the GLSL version.